# How to use com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium in eclipse while writing the scripts?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, thoughtworks-go

While writing the scripts in eclipse by using selenium RC i got an error in com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.And the com,thoughtworks.selenium class in missing in my library. Could any one suggest the remedy?

Answer (score -1):

Download the jar file supported for selenium RC and related java client libraries. Import these jar into project. Many sources are available online .

Comment: I have already downloaded the jar file and imported it to the eclipse. And then build the path, but it shows the error in the corresponding line.and there is no such package,how can i add that?